# Compare $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ if $X \leq Y$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Assume that non-neqative random variables $X$ and $Y$ are defined at the same probability space and $X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X < Y) > 0$.

It is clear from in this case that

$$
\mathbb{E}(X) \leq\mathbb{E}(Y)
$$

The question: is the following stronger statement true

$$
\mathbb{E}(X) < \mathbb{E}(Y)
$$
?

Comment: Yes.$\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: This is clear from the definition of expectation, $\mathbb E[X]=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\mathbb P$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true, let $Z=Y-X$, then $Z\geqslant 0$ a.s and $\mathbf{P}(Z>0)>0$. Let us suppose that $\mathbf{E}(X)=\mathbf{E}(Y)$, then $\mathbf{E}(Z)=0$ and therefore $Z=0$ a.s (because $Z\geqslant 0$ a.s) which means that $X=Y$ a.s. This contradicts the fact that $\mathbf{P}(Z>0)>0$, therefore $\mathbf{E}(X)<\mathbf{E}(Y)$.